# Which type of cannon does this housing in the remains of the Death Star II belong to?

Tags: star-wars, death-star, object-identification, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker*, during the fight between Kylo Ren and Rey on an almost-submerged wreckage of the second Death Star, visible in the background is what appears to be the sole survivor of the tens of thousands of low altitude XX-9 heavy Turbolaser turrets like the ones we saw in *Return of the Jedi* (1983).

[image: Cannon on Death Star wreckage, from The Rise of Skywalker]

However, I am speculating because the mentioned type of cannon was only capable of positive pitch (elevation) a bit over 90 degrees, and it was located on top of the towers. That's why I ask if someone knows exactly to which type of cannon this naked housing belongs to. Is it an unknown defense weapon or it is just a tribute to one of the iconic Turbolasers that terrorized us during the original trilogy?

[image: Rey in front of a damaged cannon, from The Rise of Skywalker]

Comment: That's not a gun, that's an [Engine order telegraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_order_telegraph); it's set to "Full Astern."

Comment: Is it a canon cannon?

Comment: @Valorum - Any. Canon or Legend.

Comment: @Valorum Only if it doesn't shoot first

Comment: Are we sure it's a cannon? Looks like it could just be some mechanical component.

Comment: "*She hardly recalled traveling any distance, but somehow they ended up outside the wreckage, on a bridgelike hunk of metal only meters wide. **A massive gun turret** loomed over them; beyond it and half drowning in spray was Ren’s parked TIE. The ocean raged all around, but she pressed her attack, oblivious to the added danger.*" - That's all you get from the novel

Comment: There's nothing useful in the *Art of Rise of Skywalker* book. Just some concept of them fighting

Comment: Link of Prop Store 2016 auction lote 477 for one turbo cannon tower (less than 3 inch tall). Original constructed by ILM for ROTJ. Winning bid:£2,750. The internal mechanisms of the cannons have certain resemblances to the OP's. It's probably worthy to revise some old blueprints from artists lke Joe Johnston, Doug Chiang, etc.

https://propstoreauction.com/view-auctions/catalog/id/44/lot/9804/#